# Is it bad to have triangles in the model?

Tags: modeling

I am a beginner in Blender and have some questions now after some experimentation.

I'm making the face of a character (pictured below) and have no idea if I'm doing it right. Read a bit about edge flow, but also read something about avoiding triangles. As you can see in the picture, I have some triangles.

When does this become a problem? (I intend to animate the model when it is finished)

[image]

Comment: If you want to understand why it's bad, add a subdivision surface to your model and crank up the levels. But triangles aren't as bad as 5+ N-gons. Also, they disrupt edge flow. You should be able to add an edge loop around the mouth without disruption. But all in one it's pretty subjective, if that model suits your needs go for it. Anyway the best way to understand why it's good or bad is to experience by yourself the limitations of your workflow (in my opinion)

Comment: Quads are certainly better but don't feel like you absolutely have to avoid triangles.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks, but if I get unwanted results, how do I know it's the triangles that are causing it? Any special signs?